# Flatlib use current date and time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime, pyephem

Can someone help with me this?

I am using Flatlib to compute planet positions, but the code for entering the date and time for computation is fixed, so you have to update it each time.

Is there a way to using `datetime.now()` [or another way] to complete the fields in the `Datetime()` automatically? I can't get the code in the `date = Datetime()` to accept any form of `datetime` code.

I looking to get `Datetime()` to accept month/day/year and hour:minute:second format eg (08/24/2018, 21:17:00)

With the below code i get the following error:

C:\Users\famil>C:\Users\famil\Desktop\flatlib_working_degree.py
('{0.month}/{0.day}/{0.year}', '21:15:41')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\famil\Desktop\flatlib_working_degree.py", line 13, in 
    date = Datetime(x)
  File "C:\Users\famil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flatlib\datetime.py", line 177, in **init**
    self.date = Date(date, calendar)
  File "C:\Users\famil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flatlib\datetime.py", line 76, in **init**
    self.jdn = int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

```
from flatlib.datetime import Datetime
from flatlib.geopos import GeoPos
from flatlib.chart import Chart
from flatlib import const
import datetime

# set date and time to now

now = datetime.datetime.now()
x = '{0.month}/{0.day}/{0.year}, {0.hour}:{0.minute}:{0.second}'.format(now)
print(x)
date = Datetime(x)
pos = GeoPos('53n15', '2e31')

chart = Chart(date, pos, hsys=const.HOUSES_PLACIDUS, IDs=const.LIST_OBJECTS)  

# calculate body and degree value
asc = chart.get(const.ASC)
print(asc, asc.lon)
sun = chart.get(const.SUN)
print(sun, sun.lon, sun.movement())
moon = chart.get(const.MOON)
```

Comment: Could you not continue using strftime to create the formats it wants? It seems very odd to provide no interop with native dates and times though.

Comment: hey jon... in case i need to spell out... i'm pretty new to this coding thing... i have things i want to do that can only be done with code so here i am... how would i continue to use strftime to get the code working?!

Comment: Well your code is already creating a string from a datetime, which seems to be what the flatlib API wants, so what's the specific problem you have? Give a [mcve] that illustrates the specific problem; you don't even seem to be *using* `now`.

Comment: [Edit] the question. But with code that shows the attempt to get strings from datetime into Datetime, because neither snippet you've posted does. It seems to accept strings; there are plenty of resources about getting strings from datetimes already.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that `foo('bar', 'baz')` is fundamentally different to `foo('bar, baz')`. Also your current example doesn't tell the reader what you expected to happen in that code, and what happened instead.

Answer (score 3):

Flatlib's Datetime demands 2 separate inputs for **date** and **time**, as you can check here: [Github: flatlib/datetime.py](https://github.com/flatangle/flatlib/blob/master/flatlib/datetime.py)
.

```
def __init__(self, date, time=0, utcoffset=0, calendar=GREGORIAN):
```

But your code has only ***datetime*** 1 argument, separated by comma. That's incorrect:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = Datetime(now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M"))
```

You should write it like this:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = Datetime(now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"), now.strftime('%H:%M'))
```